# C++ Circular buffer through Circular iterator

Tags: c++, circular-list

I saw some question on SO lately involving circular buffer, *like a chain of descriptors for data transfer*. All solutions involved lots of lines.

I wanted an implementation with as few lines as possible, as inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947754/3972710). The idea is not to have a circular buffer but a usual container and a specific iterator able to wrap.

*Question*: Is it possible to achieve this with as few lines as in the example below or are there hidden pitfalls ?

- This code was intended to spin forever on a container which size do not change, more information about [iterator validity under containers changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

*Additional information after first answers / comments*

[Similar 2009 question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782019/easiest-way-to-make-a-cyclic-iterator-circulator) mentioned by Mercury Dime (the question uses the term *cyclic* or *circulator* and not *circular*)

*EDIT: Corrections of the more evident errors / typos based on* [incomputable's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166018/56898)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <class BaseIter>
class CircularIterator:public BaseIter {
        //inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/947754/3972710
        BaseIter begin,end;
    public:
        CircularIterator(BaseIter b, BaseIter e ):BaseIter(b), begin(b), end(e) {}
        CircularIterator & operator ++(void)
        {
            BaseIter::operator++();
            if(*this == end)
                BaseIter::operator=(begin);
            return *this;
        }
        const CircularIterator   operator ++(int)
        {
            const auto oldValue = *this;
            this->operator++();
            return oldValue;
        };

        CircularIterator & operator --(void) = delete;
        const CircularIterator   operator --(int)  = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<int> intList = { 1, 2, 3};
    CircularIterator<std::list<int>::iterator> circIter(intList.begin(),intList.end());

    auto it = circIter++;

    std::cout << *(it++) << "\n";
    std::cout << *(it++) << "\n";
    std::cout << *(it++) << "\n";
    std::cout << *(it++) << "\n";
    std::cout << "..." << "\n";
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

*Original Code*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
//C++11 at least

template <class baseIter>
class circularIterator:public baseIter {
        //inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/947754/3972710
        baseIter begin,end;
    public:
        circularIterator(baseIter b, baseIter e ):baseIter(b), begin(b), end(e) {}
        baseIter & operator ++(void) {  baseIter::operator++();
                                        if(*this == end) baseIter::operator=(begin);
                                        return *this;}
        baseIter & operator ++(int) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    list<int> intList = { 1, 2, 3};
    circularIterator<list<int>::iterator> circIter(intList.begin(),intList.end());

    cout << *circIter << endl;
    cout << *(++circIter) << endl;
    cout << *(++circIter) << endl;
    cout << *(++circIter) << endl;
    cout << *(++circIter) << endl;
    cout << "..." << endl;

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::list uses [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). `*(--circIter)` with circIter = begin will cause problems in your example. std::vector uses random access iterators, which will introduce even more problems.

Comment: @MercuryDime, I don't see how that is relevant (I'm not OP). Getting out of the range is problem of the user.

Comment: You're right, I'm getting confused as to what should happen internally with memory (wrap around end), and what should happen with the iterators. (they don't wrap) This is what I was thinking of: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782019/easiest-way-to-make-a-cyclic-iterator-circulator)

Comment: @MercuryDime, I'm not really sure what you wanted to say about the linked post. Could you please clarify?

Comment: In my first post, my thinking was - "the iterator needs to wrap around both ends". (as shown in Thomas Witt's code in the link) I was wrong.

Comment: @Mercury Dime: good point for your link to the SO question on "cyclic" iterator. Before posting my code review I naturally looked at other posts through googling, but keeping the term "circular" instead of "cyclic" prevented me to find it

Answer (score 4):

**High level overview:**

The idea is solid, but creating an iterator adapter to make the container behave differently just sounds weird. It would be better to have container adapters, as `std::stack<>` and `std::queue<>` do.

**Implementation overview:**

The code has a serious issues. Mainly the following:

- **It has a chance to break on some algorithms:**

  ```
   auto second = ++first;
  ```

where `first` is `circularIterator<>` will make `second` to be `baseIter`.  The most dangerous ones are sorting algorithms, especially those that use divide and conquer. The template type parameter is usually only one, e.g. only one type of iterators are allowed, as a result the compiler will issue substitution failure error.

- **Will not work on idiomatic `while (*first++ != last)` or similar.**

The postfix increment is deleted, thus it disables probably most of the standard library.

- **The class pretends to be an iterator, but is a range.**

Usually iterator should know about its own internal state only. Knowing end iterator should be last resort. Actually, the reason for storing the range is because the code doesn't provide a function to create a pair of `circularIterator`s. If such function would be provided, the `operator==()` of parent iterator would still work, as they mostly take it by reference.

**Cosmetics:**

Not really important, but here they are:

- Usually people name types (and classes, as a result) in PascalCase or snake_case. Starting with a lowercase letter, camelCase is used for variable names.
- Indentation and brace placing is very weird.

**Misc:**

- `using namespace std;` is bad. It causes name clashes and in general confuses other mechanisms of C++.
- `std::endl` is a performance drainer. If done in a tight loop, can cause serious issues. [Bjarne Stroustrup himself didn't use it for a decade.](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/357#issuecomment-153515258)

Comment: I hope I corrected the most evident errors / typos I made, like returning BaseIter instead of CircularIterator for the  ++ operator. I added a few lines even if I had "packed" my code so that length was minimal. As I am only looking for forward iterator in my case I deleted the -- operators... Let me time to think about your other architectural proposals

Comment: @NGI, on CodeReview changing code means invalidating answers. Please post a follow up instead when you're fully ready.

Comment: My excuses. I put again the original code at the end of the question. Some errors were big enough to be corrected so that I prefer to leave this update anyway, but I take into account your advice to publish the new code only when fully done

Comment: @NGI, there is nothing with original code. It works, though may lead to traps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `(void)` where you mean `()`.  Stroustrup calls this "an abomination" and it has no purpose in C++.  It was necessary in ANSI C in order to adopt C++ declaration syntax while still retaining the old style, but in C++ an empty parameter list means no parameters, pure and simple.